# Chrome Remote Desktop doesn't run in 1080p

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, remote-control, remote-access

I connect to my laptop via my Galaxy Tab S 8.4 tablet.  When I do I expect my tablet to have a nice sharp look to it, but I see blurring artifacts on screen - it seems that some sort of lower resolution is used despite my tablet being capable of 1600 x 2560.  I am able to control my laptop so I know the app works correctly, I just am disappointed with the visuals.

Is there someway to force Remote Desktop to use a crisp resolution?

Comment: I think they're just compression artifacts. I've remoted from a 1080p Windows machine into a 1366x768 machine and I still get some pixelation and blur, especially in gradient regions. CRD is probably trying to compress the stream aggressively ([it uses VP8](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/next-step-in-chrome-os-journey.html), apparently).

Comment: Unfortunate, but makes sense.